# gnuplot using vertically stored datafile

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to figure out the basic syntax to draw a line graph of a server's disk usage.  The data is stored in a Oracle database which obviously stores new data on separate rows, not on the same row.  From what I have read so far, gnuplot seems to prefer related data to be on the same row.  My data looks like this.

```
#disk date     GB_used
disk1 20121022 99
disk1 20121023 104
disk2 20121022 170
disk2 20121023 182
```

Can gnuplot handle data in this format?  The graph output would have 2 lines, one for disk1 and one for disk2.  The data file only has a few disk_numbers but will eventually contain hundreds of rows from records for each day.

Comment: gnuplot takes each point from a single row.  The set of points is stacked vertically -- Which is pretty much what you have.  The place where your datafile fails to conform is that you don't add blank records to separate data groupings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to plot GB_used vs date for disk1 and disk2.  If that's the case, this is *almost* the format gnuplot likes:

```
#disk date     GB_used
disk1 20121022 99
disk1 20121023 104


disk2 20121022 170
disk2 20121023 182
```

Here's a simple awk script to convert it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline;x=$1;print $0}{if($1!=x){print '\n\n';print$0;x=$1}else{print $0}}' example.dat
```

In this case, gnuplot would want you to separate the two datasets by 1 or 2 blank lines.  If you separate by 1 blank line, gnuplot will plot 2 lines of the same linetype

If you separate by 2 blank lines, gnuplot will plot both data sets, and you can make it plot with different line types:

```
plot for [idx=0:1] 'example.dat' i idx u 2:3 w lines
```

Essentially the same effect can be achieved by filtering as demonstrated in the answer by @andyras

Comment: Something is not working: gnuplot> plot for [idx=0:1] 'example.dat' i idx u 2:3 w lines ...returns "invalid expression", pointing to "["

Comment: @user584583 -- What version of gnuplot do you have?  If you're on gnuplot 4.2, the iteration won't work (iteration was introduced in gnuplot 4.3 -- the current stable version is 4.6).

Comment: My version is an old one and upgrading will not happen this year where I work (Initech).

Comment: @user584583 -- the above line with iteration is equivalent to:  `plot 'example.dat' i 0 u 2:3 w lines, 'example.dat' i 1 u 2:3 w lines` without iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can, but you may have to trick it a bit.  Here is the basic plot command:

```
plot "< sed 's/^disk//' data.dat" using ($1==1?$2:1/0):3 title 'disk 1', \
 '' using ($1==2?$2:1/0):3 title 'disk 2'
```

First I run the data file through `sed` to remove the string 'disk' from each row.  Then gnuplot makes a conditional comparison after the `using` keyword.  In the first plot command, it checks if the first data column is equal to 1 (which it would be for 'disk1' - 'disk'), if so it plots the second column vs. the third, else it plots 1/0 (which gnuplot ignores).

I tried doing it in pure gnuplot:

```
plot 'data.dat' u ($1 eq 'disk1'?$2:1/0):3 t 'disk 1', \
 '' u ($1 eq 'disk2'?$2:1/0):3 t 'disk 2'
```

but it did not like the string comparison in the plot command.

To get the time format right you will want to do something like

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y%m%d'
set format x '%F'
```

before the plot command.

EDIT:
As @mgilson pointed out, the `strcol` command can be used if you want a 'pure gnuplot' solution:

```
plot 'data.dat' u (strcol(1) eq 'disk1'?$2:1/0):3 t 'disk 1', \
     '' u (strcol(1) eq 'disk2'?$2:1/0):3 t 'disk 2'
```

Comment: This is the first time I've answered a gnuplot question and been notified that someone else answered while I was typing.

Comment: In your pure gnuplot example, you might be able to work it with `strcol(1) eq 'disk1'` instead of `$1 eq 'disk1'`